# Re-execute a function if it fails (R)

Tags: r

I have a function f that is 95% a giant for loop (the specifics of the function are not relevant). While the function works properly, it sometimes stops working (for various reasons). Due to the design of f, when re-executed, it restarts from the point of interruption and continues working properly until it either finishes or it stops and has to be restarted again. The first approach would obviously be to "locate and fix the bugs", which will be done at some point. However, in the meanwhile, the function must be producing results. My question is, is there a way to re-execute it automatically?

e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
execute(f)

if(f fails){

execute(f)

} else {}
```

When f is finally finished, we move on to a different part of the code.

So my question is, is this doable? Many thanks!

Comment: See `?try` or `?tryCatch`.

Comment: Unfortunately it will not work, have tried it extensively. Due to the nature of what I am doing, I am asking specifically for re-execution, not for ignore the error and move on.

Comment: @nicola to be fair, the "try" and "restarts" systems in R are complicated and poorly documented.

Comment: @Iason there's more to it than just ignoring errors. See [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/error-handling-in-r/) for an example; search for `withRestarts`

Comment: You don't need to "move on". You can order  another execution if it fails. Something like `repeat {if (!(inherits(try(execute(f)),"try-error"))) break}`.

Comment: @shadowtalker, I will give it an even more extensive look and return if it does not work out : )

Comment: @shadowtalker I found the doc very useful and well written. It's not complicated at all and it's well documented IMO.

Comment: @nicola your solution is good but it wasn't obvious to me. It would be good if you could post that as an answer, along with a brief explanation and a pointer to the relevant docs.

Comment: @shadowtalker I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `try`. It's a standard R function, takes an expression as argument and returns the value the expression returns if it runs correctly or an object of class `try-error` if an error occurred. For instance:

```
a<-try(2+2)
a
#[1] 4
class(a)
#[1] "numeric"
a<-try(2+"")
class(a)
#[1] "try-error"
```

As you can see, you can enclose an expression in a `try`, then check whether the returned object inherits from `try-error` and decide what to do in either case. In your case you can:

```
repeat {
    tmp<-try(execute(f))
    if (!(inherits(tmp,"try-error"))) 
      break
}
```

Above, I try to `execute(f)`. If it runs correctly, the loop exits. If not, it keeps trying.